# how execute PowerShell command in Azure Function Apps?

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-functions

Azure have a built-in PowerShell in it's portal and you can write your commands directly from Portal without installing PowerShell in your system.
how I can write (execute) my PowerShell commands inside the function Apps?

Comment: New Function App --> PowerShell?

Comment: what you mean by New Function app--> PowerShell?
I want to write my commands in Function Apps using programming languages like python, javascript and etc.

Comment: Then it would help to provide a decent level of detail with your question. Do you want to call a PowerShell script from Python?

Comment: I don't want to call a PowerShell Script. I want to write PowerShell Commands directly in my code. using Python, C++, C#, Java, Javascript and any other languages that it is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This blog post may be able to help.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2017/02/24/using-powershell-modules-in-azure-functions/

Comment: Thank You, I will tell you the result

Comment: it's using Classic Portal, but it help me so much. thanks for your advice